# Trying to make it so function main() recognizes specific integers when calling upon function problem_solving

Tags: python

I am a total novice so bear with me here.  Basically, I want the main() function to be able to pick up on a specific integer.  As in, if my input for step_graded was '1', I could write gradeforstep = problem_solving('1') and be taken to stepgrade=input('Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step 1:').  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def problem_solving(step_graded):
    if step_graded == '1':
        stepgrade=input('Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step 1:')
        finalstepgrade1 = f"Step: {step_graded} Grade: {stepgrade}."
        return finalstepgrade1
    if step_graded == '2':
        stepgrade=input('Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step 2:')
        finalstepgrade = f"Step: {step_graded} Grade: {stepgrade}."
        return finalstepgrade
    if step_graded == '3':
        stepgrade=input('Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step 3:')
        finalstepgrade = f"Step: {step_graded} Grade: {stepgrade}."
        return finalstepgrade
    if step_graded == '4':
        stepgrade=input('Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step 4:')
        finalstepgrade = f"Step: {step_graded} Grade: {stepgrade}."
        return finalstepgrade

def main():
    gradeforstep = problem_solving(input)
    print (gradeforstep)
main()
```

Comment: Where do you set `input`? Also, you shouldn't use `input` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in function that's used very frequently.

Comment: All your `if` blocks are essentially the same. The only difference is the number in the prompt, which is the same as `step_graded`. Why don't you just put the variable into the prompt?

Comment: I have input after stepgrade=.  Should I change that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by putting the variable into the prompt?

Comment: `stepgrade = input(f'Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step {step_graded}:')`

Comment: I was talking about the variable  in `gradeforstep = problem_solving(input)`. You need to assign the variable that's being used as the argument.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again but I'm still confused.  What should I change input to?  Should I change it to stepgraded, or individual numbers?.  I tried again after changing stepgrade to do the  gradeforstep = problem_solving('1') thing that i mentioned but it still didn't work.

Comment: If you want to get the number from the user, do `step = input("What step")` and then `problem_solving(step)`

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't connect to the other function and go to step grade right after.  Instead it repeated like this before going to stepgrade:

What step?1
Which step (1-4) is being graded?1
Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step 1

Comment: Nevermind, you answered worked.  Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of `step_graded` from the user before calling `problem_solving`.

You can simplify `problem_solving` because all the cases are the same except for the step number, which you can substitute using the variable.

```
def problem_solving(step_graded):
    stepgrade=input(f'Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step {step_graded}:')
    finalstepgrade = f"Step: {step_graded} Grade: {stepgrade}."
    return finalstepgrade

def main():
    step = input("What step have you done:")
    gradeforstep = problem_solving(step)
    print (gradeforstep)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what might work. First, I simplified your `problem_solving()` function by using the `step_graded` argument explicitly; next, I replaced the `main()` function (which is likely a C-relic) with the pythonic way of doing things (i.e. the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause); finally, I used sys.argv to read in the `step_graded` variable from the command line.

```
import sys

def problem_solving(step_graded):
    stepgrade = input(f'Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step {step_graded}: ')
    finalstepgrade = f'Step: {step_graded} Grade: {stepgrade}'
    return finalstepgrade

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('argument missing for step_graded.')
        exit(1)

    step_graded = sys.argv[1]
    response = problem_solving(step_graded)
    print(response)
```

Thus, if you save the code as, say, `mycode.py`, then you run it as:

```
$> python mycode.py 3
Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step 3: 2
Step: 3 Grade: 2
```